# Why some packages included with Emacs don't have their documentation in the main manual?

Tags: ido, documentation, manual

I wanted to read the [Ido documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/ido.html) offline from Emacs.

I read in the `NEWS` file of Emacs 24.5 that since the 24.4 version an "*Ido user manual is now included*" (line 608). But it was not possible to find anything in the main manual about Ido.

Then, after searching more, I found out that the `info-display-manual` command made possible to reach the `ido` manual. I also found later that it was listed in the INFO tree (`M-x info-directory`).

I admit that I should have known more about how to access `info-display-manual` and the INFO tree, but why these kind of  packages (part of the vanilla Emacs) are not linked in the [main manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/emacs.html) (as far as I know)?

Comment: What is the "main manual"?

Comment: Instructive question @T.Verron: I thought the main directory for documentation was what is found at [`M-x info emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/emacs.html)` and didn't know there was an upper directory (`M-x info ret`). Sorry, I wasn't very aware of the `Info`  usage, maybe because I used mostly a paper manual until there.

Comment: @T.Verron note that the top level of the info directory contains more than just Emacs documentation. Many Linux programs install info manuals, even ones that have nothing to do with Emacs. I have info manuals for LaTeX2e, Maxima, R etc. None of these are part of Emacs. So I think it is correct to consider the Emacs info file to be the 'main manual'. This is what you see when you call `info-emacs-manual`, `C-h r`.

Comment: @Tyler Yes, I know "info" contains much more than emacs, but I didn't know about `info-emacs-manual`.

Comment: @T.Verron sorry, I misinterpreted your comment!

Answer (score 1):

Good question! I see that `ido` isn't listed in the index, nor does it appear anywhere outside the 'Acknowledgements' section of the Emacs manual. Presumably that's because the Emacs manual is already huge, and is meant to deal only with the core functions of Emacs.

A lot of core components have their own manuals: RefTex, org-mode, CC mode etc. However, most of these are linked from the Emacs manual at appropriate locations. If you find a spot where it would make sense to link to the `ido` manual, that may be worth submitting as a documentation bug.

Comment: After reading upper @t-verron comment, I understood it was a bad understanding that I always had of the Info documentation reader usage  and the associated "root" of manuals. I'll think of checking if it should be improved or if this is my only fault of dumb user.

Comment: Actually there have always been some authors of packages that refuse to provide an info interface. Such packages have their own ways of triggering help screens. In almost all their cases, it is impossible to integrate and to remember to trigger the screens differently. Helm is one of them.

Comment: @EmacsUser I think this is different - helm has no info manual, so there's nothing to link to from the Emacs info manual. Also, helm isn't part of the Emacs core. Ido is part of Emacs core, and does have an info manual. So there's no reason it couldn't be linked.

Comment: In my normal workflow, I usually don't think in terms of core and not core. But I understand your point that one deserves to be more integrated than the other.